# Spresense CAM_IMGSIZEについて

Tags: spresense

Spresense CAM_IMGSIZEで5Mを撮影しようと思っておりますが、撮影できません。
下記コードを使用しておりますが、何か誤りないかご指摘いただけませんでしょうか。

```c
include SDHCI.h
include SPI.h
include Camera.h

SDClass theSD;

void setup() {
 theSD.begin();
 theCamera.begin();
 pinMode(LED3, OUTPUT); 
 theCamera.setStillPictureImageFormat(
    CAM_IMGSIZE_5M_H    // 5Mサイズ設定
    ,CAM_IMGSIZE_5M_V   // 5Mサイズ設定
    ,CAM_IMAGE_PIX_FMT_JPG);
}

void loop() {
 CamImage img = theCamera.takePicture();
 if (img.isAvailable()) { 
  File myFile = theSD.open("TIMG2.JPG",FILE_WRITE);
  myFile.write(img.getImgBuff(),img.getImgSize());
  digitalWrite(LED3, HIGH); 
  delay(100); //追加
  digitalWrite(LED3, LOW); 
  myFile.close();
  while(1);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。

お問い合わせの5M解像度の撮影についてお答えいたします。

ご不便をお掛けし申し訳ございませんが、現在のソフトウェアでは
5M解像度の撮影に対応しておりません。
本件につきましては現在対応を検討しております。

今後ともSPRESENSEをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

SPRESENSEサポートチーム