# Sony Spresenseのカメラの動画保存

Tags: spresense

Spresenseで動画が取れるようになりますか？
長時間動かすと、連番JPGではファイル数が多くなりすぎます。
AVIなどのコンテナにまとめたsampleコード.inoは提供される予定はありますでしょうか？

せっかくHDビデオ出力 1080p（1920×1030 30 frame/s）と仕様にあるので、
それが取れるサンプルコードがあると良いのですが。

Comment: 「何か手法はないか」は特に問題ありませんが、「サンプルを提供する予定があるかどうか」については製品サポート (Sony) にしか分かり得ないので、このような質問は実際の製品サポート宛に問い合わせることを検討してください。

Answer (score 0):

昔、同じような質問に答えたような気がするなぁ...と思ったら、昔同じ質問をされてますね？

[Spresenseで動画を撮りたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/59454/spresense%e3%81%a7%e5%8b%95%e7%94%bb%e3%82%92%e6%92%ae%e3%82%8a%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84)

今回は、HDでということでしょうか？（もしそうなら質問の文言を変えたほうがよいのでは？？）HDはメモリ的に難しいということはすでに議論されていて、それでもHDで取得したいという場合は、次のやりとりを参照されるのがよいかと。（さすがに30fpsはムリでしょうけど）

[spresenseカメラの解像度の有効な設定について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/59221/spresense%e3%82%ab%e3%83%a1%e3%83%a9%e3%81%ae%e8%a7%a3%e5%83%8f%e5%ba%a6%e3%81%ae%e6%9c%89%e5%8a%b9%e3%81%aa%e8%a8%ad%e5%ae%9a%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6?rq=1)

個人的には、JPEGの圧縮率を変更できるようにAPIを追加するか、どこかのAPIに引数を追加してほしいなぁと思っています。

以上、ご参考になれば。